# Nextjs, Gatsby for Server-side-rendering of an e-commerce website with Django at the backend?

Tags: django, reactjs, redux, gatsby, next.js

I want to make an e-commerce web app, where at the backend I am using **Django** and Django Rest Framework. 
I want to use **React, Redux and React-Router** with axios library at frontend. I found-out that these are two other framework for React i.e. **Nextjs and Gatsby**.

Now, Which one will be better for me to make an e-commerce web app between **Nextjs and Gatsby**?

And, Is it necessary to use **Redux, React-Router with Nextjs and Gatsby**?

Answer (score 5):

It all *depends* on, what are the important performance related features you want to have in your app? I assume you have the basic understanding of how these both frameworks work. Still, I'll try to make it as brief as possible.

***NextJs*** uses **Server-side rendering(SSR)** which is good for your *SEO* and *initial site load*. It uses a concept of *pages*, meaning each page is in itself a route. So you *don't need to implement React-router* separately. It has it's own routing mechanism which can be found in [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction).

***Gatsby*** is a **static site generator tool**. A static site generator generates static HTML on build time. It doesn’t use a server. Gatsby uses GraphQL which is a query language and if you’re familiar with SQL, it works in a very similar way. Using a special syntax, you describe the data you want in your component and then that data is given to you.

*The fundamental difference is, NextJs requires a server to be able to run. Gatsby can function without any server at all. Gatsby just generates pure HTML/CSS/JS at build time, whereas NextJs creates HTML/CSS/JS at run time. So each time a new request comes in, it creates a new HTML page from the server.*

And yes ***Redux*** implementation is **consistent** across these platforms and other state management. Though the Gatsby needs some plugins to get started with it. NextJs setup is similar to create-react-app's. And it entirely depends whether you want to go with redux or not. It has a specific use-case. Nowadays, you have partial solutions for these use-cases i.e contextAPI, hooks etc. But still you need redux for many others, where these limited solutions won't work.

***So, If your back-end is in GraphQL, I would recommend to look into Gatsby, it provides some of the powerful solutions for front-end. That said, I would recommend you to go on with NextJs, if you are using any other back-end architecture. I myself had implemented an e-commerce site in NextJs and I must admit It was a great working experience for me.***

Comment: Thanks. Is it necessary to use **React** framework like **Nextjs or Gatsby**? What will be the problem if I only use **React library** without using **Nextjs or Gatsby**?
And to complete production ready app, What tools are need? Like (**Django+Django Rest+Django-Allauth+Rest-Auth+React+Redux+Nextjs+Axios+Material-UI**)

Comment: You indeed can build the app without nextjs or gatsby. These are just frameworks like 'create-react-app' with more specifications which can be handy in some cases and also can create additional bottlenecks at times. So, `You can build the app with **React Library**`, there are many solutions in the market running perfectly fine.

Comment: Please give some solutions name when only use react library. And when use **Nextjs**, does it need other tools?

Comment: Do you have any prior experience working with react in production? Or you are new to it? I just want to know, what really is bothering you in process of selection of frameworks.

Comment: I would recommend you to go through this article, to wrap your head around 'create-react-app' boilerplate and NextJs. After reading this article you will be able to make a better & informed decision about these frameworks for your use-case. 

[LINK](https://blog.logrocket.com/next-js-vs-create-react-app/)

Comment: I have full knowledge of reactjs, redux, react-router, material-ui, ant-design, axios and also backend part django, django-rest. I work with all of this. But I don't make any production project. I want make it with full secure way. I get some tools new in day by day. That's why I face some problem which one need to choose. That's why I want to know to make a fully secure production ecommerce app, does i need some other tools?? hope u understand:)

Comment: I get it now. I would dearly recommend you to go for NextJS. I am speaking from my own personal experience, the learning curve is not that steep, you will easily adopt to it's framework and it has some additive advantages which come with production ready app.

Comment: Thanks Sir, So for backend (**django + django-rest + django-allauth + rest-auth**) and for frontend (**Nextjs + Redux + Axios + Material-UI**)...Anything else to make fully secure production e-commerce app like amazon(not that much advance but It can start my business with users)?? Please tell me.

Comment: That looks good to me. I would highly recommend to make use of hooks - **useReducer, useContext** etc. - wherever and whenever you can instead of resorting to redux straight away. Secondly, use **useFetch** from **use-http** package, if you will be using hooks instead of Axios, its very productive hook for making api calls.

Comment: @Jawadulhassan I want to build a website where there is an option to login(google) and logged in user will have some pages to upload some images or update some contents. Do you suggest I should use NextJS or Gatsby would be fine for this? Landing page is faster with Gatsby as it has good plugins for image management. so I am impressed by that. Please suggest.

Comment: @stafan its true that landing page is faster for Gatsby but the nextJS is still faster than CRA and difference between Gatsby and nextJS would be negligible in real-time, a user won't be able to differentiate between them. What differentiate them both, is the getting hold of re-rendering and learning curve & applications, from 'create-react-app' to 'nextJS' and from 'create-react-app' to 'Gatsby'. Updating content would go like this, CRA > NextJs > Gatsby because of Client-side rendering, Server-side rendering and Static build, respectively.